# Передача данных между несколькими формами и отображение "на лету" - C#WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь решить следующую задачу. (C# WinForms)

Есть три формы:

- На **Form1** текстбокс и две кнопки, по нажатии на одну кнопку появляется
  Form2, на другую Form3.
- На **Form3** лишь один текстбокс.
- На **Form2** текстбокс и кнопка, по нажатии на которую данные из
  тексбокса на **Form2** должны отобразиться в текстбоксах **Form1** и **Form3**.

Пытался найти ответ тут ([Ответы на 7 самых частых вопросов по WinForms - C#](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread110436.html)), но там описывается только взаимодействие между одной главной одной и подчинённой формой (что можно увидеть в коде прикреплённом ниже).

Как передать и отобразить данные введённые в текстбокс **Form2** в текстбокс **Form3** даже тогда, когда **Form3** уже открыта? Как дописать код?

Form1:

```
namespace WindowsFormsAppTEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 F2 = new Form2();
            F2.Owner = this;
            F2.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 F3 = new Form3();
            F3.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
namespace WindowsFormsAppTEST
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 main = this.Owner as Form1;
            main.textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Form3:

```
namespace WindowsFormsAppTEST
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Form1 F1 = new Form1();
            textBox1.Text = F1.textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращение к любой форме приложения делает через её непосредственный вызов из списка открытых форм.

```
Form1 form1 = (Form1) Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
if (form1 != null)
    form1.textBox.Text = "Bla Bla BLa";
```

Если вам необходимо менять содержимое полей нескольких форм "не лету", то используйте для `textBox` событие `TextChanged` в котором передавайте в нужную форму текущее содержимое `textBox`.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ)